# Without internet PrimeFaces 4.0 is not working

Tags: primefaces

Technologies are
 spring-web-flow2.3.0.
 jsf2.0
 springsecurity3.0
 primefaces4.0

I am getting below Error.
please suggest me....

Error:

18:15:47,076 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-5) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [webmvc-config.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/web-application-config.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 11 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/webmvc-config.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 21; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'faces:resources'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 11 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/webmvc-config.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 21; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'faces:resources'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:255) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 21; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'faces:resources'.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:196)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    ... 30 more

18:15:47,096 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/eSociety-web]] (MSC service thread 1-5) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [webmvc-config.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/web-application-config.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 11 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/webmvc-config.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 21; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'faces:resources'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294) [spring-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 11 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/webmvc-config.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 21; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'faces:resources'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:255) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 21; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'faces:resources'.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:196)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:390)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:322)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    ... 30 more

18:15:47,249 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-5) Initializing Mojarra 2.1.7-jbossorg-1 (20120227-1401) for context '/eSociety-web'
18:15:50,509 INFO  [org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener] (MSC service thread 1-5) Running on PrimeFaces 4.0
18:15:50,527 INFO  [org.primefaces.extensions.application.PostConstructApplicationEventListener] (MSC service thread 1-5) Running on PrimeFaces Extensions 0.6.3
18:15:50,588 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-5) Error listenerStart
18:15:50,588 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-5) Context [/eSociety-web] startup failed due to previous errors
18:15:50,589 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/eSociety-web]] (MSC service thread 1-5) Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
18:15:50,589 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (MSC service thread 1-5) Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Jan 31 18:14:22 IST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
18:15:50,591 WARN  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (MSC service thread 1-5) Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Jan 31 18:14:22 IST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347) [spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334) [spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1049) [spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]

18:15:50,596 WARN  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (MSC service thread 1-5) Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close: java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Jan 31 18:14:22 IST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360) [spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1057) [spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1010) [spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]

18:15:50,600 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/eSociety-web]] (MSC service thread 1-5) Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:171) [spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]

18:15:50,616 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./eSociety-web: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./eSociety-web: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:95)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) 
]

```
This is my webmvc-flow.xml
please suggest me.....

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:faces="http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces/spring-faces-2.4.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

    <faces:resources />

    <!-- Maps request URIs to controllers.  Here we have two kinds of flows one  is login flow and another is main flow   -->           
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <value>
                /main=flowController
                /login=loginController
            </value>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultHandler">
            <!-- Selects view names to render based on the request URI: e.g. /main selects "main" -->   
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.UrlFilenameViewController" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- it is used to handle the flow control Adaptor in 2.3.0.   This will come from spring framework.web.servlet3.2.1 -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter" />

    <!-- it trigers to the loginFlowController -->
    <bean id="loginController" class="com.LoginFlowController">
        <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Handles requests mapped to the Spring Web Flow system and ajaxHandler.
    after security we need to enable the ajax for that we need to write one property i.e ajaxHandler -->
    <bean id="flowController" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController">
        <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
         <property name="ajaxHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfAjaxHandler"/>
    </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Maps logical view names to Facelet templates in /WEB-INF (e.g. 'search' to '/WEB-INF/search.xhtml' -->
    <bean id="faceletsViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.faces.mvc.JsfView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".xhtml" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="facesContextListener"  class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowFacesContextLifecycleListener" />

   <!-- ========================= MESSAGE SOURCE DEFINITION ========================= -->
    <bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages" />

</bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Did you check that error message? What about this line? `Line 11 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/webmvc-config.xml] is invalid;`

Comment: at line number 11 i written like that "<faces:resources />" if i will remove this  total project is not working.....i.e  total ui pages are not displaying properly

Comment: We need more than just this line. I would suggest running it through some XML validator. There are even online ones. Google is your friend here.

Comment: I am attaching webmvc-flow.xml file please suggest me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue!

Using the schema location

> http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces/spring-faces-2.2.xsd

instead of

> http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces/spring-faces-2.4.xsd

(as proposed in the official documentation) worked like a charm!